# Отношение к работе программистом

Tags: работа

Добрый вечер!
В последнее время меня всё сильнее стал интересовать следующий вопрос: почему для людей возрастной категории (от 50 и выше) перспектива работы программистом не расценивается, как серьёзная профессия? То есть, если им сказать: "Я хочу работать программистом" или "Мне нравится заниматься программированием и зарабатывать этим на жизнь" - для людей вышеуказанной возрастной эти фразы практически эквивалентны какому-то лентяйству... Мне не совсем ясна эта реакция.

Интересно, почему по-вашему работа даже младшим специалистом технической поддержки, меняя картриджы и устанавливая оргтехнику, кажется людям в возрасте намного перспективнее, нежели чем работа программистом (в любой сфере, кроме, скорее всего, 1С-разработчика)?

P.S. [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), так как вопрос уже закрыт модератором, я не могу ответить на Ваш вопрос. конечно это были люди не из IT-сферы. Опрос вызвал неоднозначную реакцию, что, скорее всего, вызвано тем, что именно я изложил суть вопроса не так. вообще тема интересная для обсуждения, но не совсем удачно мной сформулированная.

Comment: Сколько респондентов было опрошено?

Comment: для чего Вам нужна эта статистика? мной было опрошено 10 человек одной возрастной категории, их реакция была приводимой к одному результату.

Comment: Откуда ты взял свою статистику? Кого и сколько опрашивал? Нормальный программист - з.п. 3к зелени - найти мне человека + 50, который скажет, что это не перспективно или средняя зп программиста, начинающего, от 1к зелени, найди сферу, где платят больше...

Comment: @LeD4eG, кто Вам сказал такую глупость ? 

Где Вы нашли такую великолепную десятку (это глядя на Ваш коммент к ответу @eprivalov1).

Comment: Нет, мое личное мнение не изменится..

Comment: Да как статистика влияет на конечное Ваше мнение?!! И причем здесь деньги?! Вы сразу начали получать 3к? Не в этом вопрос! И мне кажется, для начинающих свой путь программистов будет интересен. Не имеется в виду вопрос "Мам, а можно я пойду программистом работать?" и подобного вопроса никто напрямую не задавал. Интересует само отношение возрастной группы к данной перспективе работы в данной области. Почему так? Откуда оно берётся? На основании каких критериев они делают вывод, что этим не заработать на жизнь? Читайте внимательно вопрос, прежде чем обвинять.

Comment: Я, конечно, далек от статистики как науки, но ИМХО опрос 10 человек - этого явно недостаточно для того, чтобы по результатам такого опроса вообще делать какие-то выводы (типа "для (всех) людей вышеуказанной возрастной эти фразы практически эквивалентны следующему...").

Comment: @avp, Вам назвать имена, пароли, явки?)))
*оффтом* помниться, Хэшкод был другим. здесь можно было задать вопрос не только непосредственно связанный с программированием, но и в вопрос из околопрограммисткой сферы. как всё поменялось....

Comment: *"мной было опрошено 10 человек одной возрастной категории"* и *" почему для людей возрастной категории (от 50 и выше) перспектива работы программистом не расценивается, как серьёзная профессия"*...

Абсурд. Т.е. если, например, я опросил 10 человек одной возрастной категории и все они, например, работают дворниками, то, по вашей логике, все люди этой возрастной категории дворники? :D

PS: причем тут хэшкод?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, сам хэшкод не причём. отношение имеют люди и атмосфера на нём.
PS а как связаны Ваши посылка и заключение (Ваш очень красочный пример с дворниками) с моим вопросом?:D

Comment: @LeD4eG - самым прямым образом.

**Ваш комментарий**: "мной было опрошено 10 человек одной возрастной категории"

Comment: @LeD4eG, я реально удивился увидев такую информацию. 

Дело в том, что мне 53 и большинство знакомых той же возрастной категории. Многие сами работают в IT. В основном, конечно, менеджмент, аналитика и системная интеграция. Очень многие дети работают (пока) именно программистами (с тем или иным уклоном).

Так правда, какой социальный слой Вы опрашивали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего тот контингент, о котором Вы говорите, вырос в "Советах". И скорее всего они привыкли работать руками,именно делать что-то "физически". А сейчас настает такое время, когда работать мозгами гораздо выгоднее и легче. Но большинство людей "непробиваемые", им тяжело объяснить,что ты просидел весь день за компьютером и написал 20 строк за весь день. Но для тебя эти 20 строк- золото, ты искал,отлаживал,чистил,оптимизировал, а для них- тык-тык-тык.

Comment: ну наконец!)))Всегда радует наличие адекватных людей) Да, с одной стороны, я с Вами согласен. для них по-прежнему сидение за компьютером расценивается, как какое-то безделье. Но мне кажется есть и другой аспект. В их времена такого количества языков такой разной направленности не было. Соответственно, для них (я не знаю применимо ли это в данном случае) данная профессия не понятна, не "раскручена" что ли. Вот 1С-программист - это понятно. это бухгалтерия, кадры....

Comment: ой-ой, какой резонанс! @Автостопом_до_Рая, Ваш ответ я считаю правильным и удовлетворительным для себя. плюсую))Вы единственный выразили **действительно** своё мнение! (хотя, судя из последних комментариев - для принятия Вашего ответа слишком малое количество опрошенных)

Comment: Возможно и не так.

С другой стороны, в полтинник не шибко интересно *первично* сидеть и писать-отлаживать-чистить какие-то строчки. Строчки — это техническая часть, рутина, как-никак. Чистая же инженерная деятельность несколько выше строк кода. Это я к определенному различию между coder, programmer и systems engineer (что, впрочем, момент запутанный, т.к. на него слишком много разных мнений.)

Но это, конечно, не о тех, кто хочет в полтинник повелевать сменой картриджей и быть великим мастером копира.